# Does the regularity of the initial data have to agree with the solution's spatial regularity in evolutionary PDEs?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, regularity

Let's say we have some evolutionary PDE and the initial data $u_0$ is in the space $X$. For example $X=H^s(\Omega)$ for some $s$. My question is if the solution has to have the same spatial regularity, e.g. $u(t) \in X$ in some sense.

1. For example in the Navier-Stokes equations it is classical to take $u_0 \in H=\{u \in L^2: \text{div} u = 0\}$ and the corresponding weak solution has the regularity $u \in C_w([0,T];H)$ in 3D, where $C_w$ denotes the space of weakly continuous functions.
2. In [another paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06143) we assume $\sigma_0 \in L^2$ and we will get the regularity $\sigma \in L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap L^\infty(0,T;L^2) \cap H^1(0,T;(H^1)^*)$ of the corresponding solution. The authors then write

   > The embedding of $L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap H^1(0,T;(H^1)^*)$ into $C([0,T];L^2)$ guarantees that the initial data are meaningful.
3. In [yet another paper](https://d-nb.info/104293942X/34) this correspondence seems to be missing. E.g. we assume $\kappa_0 \in W^{1,4}$ and $v_0 \in H^1 \cap C^0$ but we will only get $\kappa \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty)$ and $v \in L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1)$. Even if we can make the $L^\infty$ to some $C_w$ or $C$ with some compactness arguments, the space regularity seems to be missing.

So my question remains, does the regularity have to agree? It could also be that I am just overlooking something in example three, I am not directly asking about that paper specifically.

I get that in one sense $u(t) \in X$ for all $t$ also means $u(0) \in X$ and it should somewhat agree. But if we assume $u_0 \in Y \subset X$, then it still makes sense, just that the initial regularity is stronger/better than the solution itself. Is that really a problem? I just see this correspondence a lot but I am not sure if it is a must.

Comment: Anything can happen. You can initialize the heat equation as rough as you want, but the solution will be infinitely smooth for positive time. Conversely, there are PDEs that can destroy any regularity at any moment (e.g. Burger's equation produces shocks). There is no general scheme and thus, there are various results for various (types of) equations.

Comment: There are several possibilities:

*gain of regularity as mentioned by Dirk
but also
*lose of derivatives as in, for instance, theorem 5.3 here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.03194.pdf) 

However, a crucial point is how (either pointwise as in C([0,T];X) or in the weak integrated sense) the initial data is reached.

Comment: For linear PDEs the classification hyperbolic/parabolic is crucial: in the parabolic case there is usually instantaneous smoothing (solutions become regular even though the initial datum is not), while in hyperbolic problems the regularity of the solution is inherited from that of the initial data and no more (think of the transport equation with constant coefficients!) And as pointed out by Guacho the (weak) meaning of "initial data" matters. For nonlinear equations anything can happen and there is no general picture.